# How to simplify this regular expression to use in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Context: Google Analytics

Need: A filter that takes given a URI or a URN (yes a URN) it returns everything up to the querystring excluded.

As you can imagine there are multiples variations out of there, which I hope I have covered in full with the list below:

```
https://sub.domain.com/path/folder/article?l=en >> expected     https://sub.domain.com/path/folder/article
https://sub.domain.com/path/folder/103#3173l=en >> expected     https://sub.domain.com/path/folder/103   
https://sub.domain.com/path/folder/103?#3173l=en >> expected     https://sub.domain.com/path/folder/103
https://sub.domain.com/path/folder/103#?3173l=en
0sub.domain.tld  >> expected sub.domain.tld
sub.domain.tld/  >> expected sub.domain.tld
sub.domain.tld?param=value  >> expected sub.domain.tld
sub.domain.tld/?param=value  >> expected sub.domain.tld
sub.domain.tld?param=value#id  >> expected sub.domain.tld
sub.domain.tld/?param=value#id  >> expected sub.domain.tld
sub.domain.tld/folder  >> expected sub.domain.tld/folder
sub.domain.tld/folder/  >> expected sub.domain.tld/folder
sub.domain.tld/folder?param=value  >> expected   sub.domain.tld/folder
sub.domain.tld/folder/?param=value  >> expected  sub.domain.tld/folder
sub.domain.tld/1/folder  >> expected      sub.domain.tld/1/folder
sub.domain.tld/1/folder/  >> expected     sub.domain.tld/1/folder
2sub.domain.tld/1/folder?param=value
3sub.domain.tld/1/folder/?param=value
4sub.domain.tld#id
5sub.domain.tld/#id
6sub.domain.tld/1#id
7sub.domain.tld/1/#id
```

The challenge I cannot solve is obtaining a regular expression that matches things in a subgroup that is always the same.

If you have to play around, I have saved a couple of tests in 
- https://regex101.com/r/trZl06/1/ 
- https://regex101.com/r/SetgFn/2

The latter is quite satisfactory at capturing my cases, but as soon as a capturing-group is added in front of the existing matching condition, the group greps even words that are not expected.

I tried also something like `((.*)(?:[\/]\?.*)|(.*)(?:\?.*))|((.*)\/$|(.*))` but the resulting subgroups are always different making the reference in the filter view a bit of a mess.

Is there anything you can think of?

Comment: Try `^([^#?]*)([/?#]?\?.*|\/$|[/#]#.*|#.*)?`, see https://regex101.com/r/fyGAJc/1

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. That's on the good way. The last bit missing is to group the trailing slash - when available - into the next group so to avoid GA traffic dispersion on pages that may be virtually the same. Unfortunately I can't implement server-side rules to solve this.

Comment: The strange thing here is that the `[/#]` doesn't seem to catch the `/`. I tried to play around the permutations, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/fyGAJc/2

Comment: I have eventually solved with a second filter in GA, stripping the last slash, but having everything in one go it is ultimately better. Thanks. I will compare the changes to understand my mistakes.

Comment: Glad my solution worked for you. Please also consider upvoting my answer if it turned out helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^([^#?]*?)([/?#]?\?.*|[/#]?#.*)?(/?)$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fyGAJc/5).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^#?]*?)` - Group 1: 0 or more chars other than `#` and `?`, as few as possible
- `([/?#]?\?.*|[/#]?#.*)?` - an optional Group 2: either of the two:

  - `[/?#]?\?.*` - an optional `/`, `?` or `#` followed with a `?` char and then the rest of the string
  - `|` - or
  - `[/#]?#.*` - an optional `/` or `#` followed with a `#` char and then the rest of the string
- `(/?)` - Group 3: an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.